# Sort featured questions by highest bounty

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounty

Can we have an option to sort featured question using their bounty?

For example, sort highest to lowest bounty value?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7753/179541.

Comment: @TLama The post is from '09 with an answer in '11. I think its worth a revisit.

Comment: @TLama this was not submitted to stackoverflow meta

Comment: @David, yep, but that's what bounty is for on SE meta. Prolly, so you would like this feature just on SO? That sounds a bit selfish..

Comment: @TLama what does the url up there say ? meta.stackoverflow or meta.stackexchange ?

Comment: Well, then I'm against this request. It would be a good feature (and even suggested at the right time, when [the site navigation is being re-designed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251095)), but not just for the SO site. [I'm personally using SO meta to get more attention, but after your comment I see that you don't]

Comment: @TLama what is wrong with being crazy about SO and not other networks ? i dont see the problem here , anyway as i said meta stackoverflow is for SO issues only , we usually close questions that dont belong to SO even if it is valid for another network so i guess same should be done for feature requests .

Comment: The new site design doesn't have this feature anymore. Please add it back!

Answer (score 8):

No! You used to but no more, sorry. (See [original answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/330350/1).) You can only filter by bounties that expire soon, or narrow it down with the other filters (e.g. tags).

The best I can offer you otherwise is that you can use control-f to search each page for your desired bounty amount. (I'm sure you knew this though!)

Comment: Why was that removed?

Comment: @Black I have no idea